# Kernel module needs to be reloaded after boot

Tags: 14.04, kernel, mouse, touchpad, modprobe

I just got my ALPS Touchpad on my Lenovo Flex 2 working (xinput returned "PS/2 Generic Mouse", now it returns two devices: "ALPS PS/2 Device" and "ALPS PS/2 Device")

But after rebooting my system it returns "PS/2 Generic Mouse" again and multitouch doesn't work anymore. dmesg returns

```
psmouse serio1: alps: Unknown ALPS touchpad: E7=73 03 0a, EC=88 b6 06
```

To make it work again I have to unloud and load the psmouse kernel module:

```
rmmod psmouse
modprobe psmouse
```

After that it works again.

By the way I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

EDIT:

It seems that the modue is being loaded too early, because after logging in I can see that the `psmouse` module is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by putting following lines into `/etc/rc.local`

```
/sbin/modprobe -r psmouse
/sbin/modprobe psmouse
```

Now Multitouch works.

Answer (score 0):

Read `man 5 modules`, it will tell you how to specify kernel modules to load at boot time. Or, just append "`psmouse`" to the `/etc/modules` file.  At "boot time", no modules are loaded, so the `rmmod` is unneeded.

Comment: Already tried that, but it didn't work. After logging in psmouse is loaded according to lsmod. Thats why I have to run rmmod.